# An sql query for a junction table

Tags: mysql

I'm wanting to write a query that pulls out a name and address of a specific person.

Names are stored in their own table.

Addresses are storied in their own table.

A junction table stands between them, which has an addressID and a personID.

```
SELECT name, address
FROM person
JOIN junctionTable ON person.personID = junctionTable.personID
JOIN personAddress ON junctionTable.personID = personAddress.addressID
WHERE junctionTable.personID = 2
```

This provides a result with the correct person but the wrong address.

This is because in the junction table we have:

addressID = 3 personID = 2

How do I pull the correct person with the correct address? Any guidance would be hugely appreciated, I am very new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second `JOIN` you need to use `addressID` on both tables.

```
SELECT name, address
FROM person
JOIN junctionTable ON person.personID = junctionTable.personID
JOIN personAddress ON junctionTable.addressID = personAddress.addressID
WHERE junctionTable.personID = 2
```

Comment: this did it! Thank you, that's so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the person address table join key:

```
SELECT name, address
FROM person
JOIN junctionTable ON person.personID = junctionTable.personID
JOIN personAddress ON person.personID = personAddress.personID
WHERE junctionTable.personID = 2
```